Zod .refine() method doesn't enforce "one of two fields required" rule in Vue 3
I'm working on a Vite/Vue 3 project and using Zod for form validation. I have a form with these two fields :
descriptionActiEconomiques and noga
I need to enforce the rule that at least one of them must be filled out. If neither field is filled, both fields should show an error with the message: "L'un des deux champs 'Description des Activités Économiques' ou 'NOGA' est requis."
My full schema look like this:
export const formSchema = [
    // Step Inscription
    z.object({

        // Unite Légale
        typeInscription: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        ide: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .regex(/^CHE\d{9}$/, {
                message: "Le format doit être 'CHE' suivi de 9 chiffres",
            }),
        nameUniteLocal: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        formeJuridique: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        pays: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        langue: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        descriptionActiEconomiques: z
            .string()
            .optional(),
        noga: z
            .string()
            .optional(),

        // Adresse
        npa: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .min(4, 'NPA non valide.')
            .max(4, 'NPA non valide.'),
        localite: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        rue: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        adresseUniteNumero: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        uniteCasePostaleNumero: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .optional(),
        uniteCasePostaleNpa: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .optional(),
        uniteCasePostaleLocalite: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .optional(),

        // Contact
        numeroTelephone: z
            .union([s1,s2]),
        emailEntreprise: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .email({
                message: 'Email non valide.'
            }),

        // Autre
        remarque: z
            .string()
            .optional(),
        attachedFile: z
            .string()
            .optional()
    }).refine((data) => data.descriptionActiEconomiques || data.noga, {
        message: "L'un des deux champs 'Description des Activités Économiques' ou 'NOGA' est requis.",
        path: ['descriptionActiEconomiques', 'noga'],
    }),

    // Step Responsable
    z.object({

        // Responsable
        responsablePersonneId: z
            .string()
            .optional(),
        responsableSexe: z
            .string()
            .optional(),
        responsablePrenom: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        responsableNom: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),

        // Contact
        responsableNumeroTelephone: z
            .union([s1,s2]),
        responsableEmail: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .email({
                message: 'Email non valide.'
            }),

        // Adresse
        responsablePays: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        responsableNpa: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            })
            .min(4, 'NPA non valide.')
            .max(4, 'NPA non valide.'),
        responsableLocalite: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        responsableRue: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
        responsableNumeroDeRue: z
            .string({
                required_error: 'Champs requis.',
            }),
    }),
]

Like you see I tried to add :
.refine((data) => data.descriptionActiEconomiques || data.noga, {
        message: "L'un des deux champs 'Description des Activités Économiques' ou 'NOGA' est requis.",
        path: ['descriptionActiEconomiques', 'noga'],
    })

But dont' work...
Expected Behavior

If both descriptionActiEconomiques and noga are left empty, the validation should fail, and an error should show for both fields with the message: "L'un des deux champs 'Description des Activités Économiques' ou 'NOGA' est requis."

Actual Behavior

No error message appears when both fields are empty.
No error in the console too.

Any ideas on why this validation rule isn't working or how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT
I tried with console.log :
.refine((data) => {
    console.log('descriptionActiEconomiques:', data.descriptionActiEconomiques);
    console.log('noga:', data.noga);

    return data.descriptionActiEconomiques || data.noga;
}, {
    message: "L'un des deux champs 'Description des Activités Économiques' ou 'NOGA' est requis.",
    path: ['descriptionActiEconomiques', 'noga'],
})

But I didn't have log in the console (no error too).

what happens when you use console.log on each of those properties inside of the refine function?

@Samathingamajig I edited my question. But no log in console.

I tried a simple example as per your usecase, and it seems to work. Can you explicitly perform a safeParse on the data, and then do .error on the result to check if the result contains any errors.
https://zod-playground.vercel.app?appdata=N4IgzgxgFgpgtgQxALhALwHQHsBGArGCAFwApgAdAOwAJrKE4ZlrMwiAnAS0oHMSBKADRVaOTuyJQA%2BgE8YCdgEZmmSgFc4OGOwHYADkU5Z6AGwHCa1MROlyFAJhUZ1m7bqwGjp81QC%2B-DHYYADNuGBIAD2oAXgA%2BagiMa0lZeSVqAB8MhKTxFLt2e0FqCktGMDAEHiZqchAAUU5JbSs82zTFaix2VptUh2pOMGoggEc1cRgAEzqLWj0ESWYAbQByZPaFVeL1tv7C1YBdP34QQRAANwQTNRgwFGWQYHpGZjqAKSwoSjrfEEPzhdtGAvCgQABmDD2SEADhAviAA
